# Spring security OAuth2 accept JSON

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-security-oauth2, spring-oauth2

I am starting with Spring OAuth2. I would like to send the username and password to /oauth/token endpoint in POST body in application/json format.

```
curl -X POST -H "Authorization: Basic YWNtZTphY21lc2VjcmV0" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{
"username": "user",
"password": "password",
"grant_type": "password"
}' "http://localhost:9999/api/oauth/token"
```

Is that possible?

Could you please give me an advice?

Comment: Why are you trying to use JSON HTTP Content Type in your request? The OAuth specification (https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6749) is very clear what content type should be used in the requests. If you follow your JSON path, your client will be bound to a bespoke implementation only compatible with your bespoke server-side code. You also won't be able to integrate with multiple OAuth providers and give the end user a choice of the login method if you would like to do so, for example: Google, Facebook, Amazon etc.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Solution (not sure if correct, but it seam that it is working):

Resource Server Configuration:

```
@Configuration
public class ServerEndpointsConfiguration extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    JsonToUrlEncodedAuthenticationFilter jsonFilter;

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .addFilterBefore(jsonFilter, ChannelProcessingFilter.class)
            .csrf().and().httpBasic().disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/test").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/secured").authenticated();
    }
}
```

Filter:

```
@Component
@Order(value = Integer.MIN_VALUE)
public class JsonToUrlEncodedAuthenticationFilter implements Filter {

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException,
            ServletException {
        if (Objects.equals(request.getContentType(), "application/json") && Objects.equals(((RequestFacade) request).getServletPath(), "/oauth/token")) {
            InputStream is = request.getInputStream();
            ByteArrayOutputStream buffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

            int nRead;
            byte[] data = new byte[16384];

            while ((nRead = is.read(data, 0, data.length)) != -1) {
                buffer.write(data, 0, nRead);
            }
            buffer.flush();
            byte[] json = buffer.toByteArray();

            HashMap<String, String> result = new ObjectMapper().readValue(json, HashMap.class);
            HashMap<String, String[]> r = new HashMap<>();
            for (String key : result.keySet()) {
                String[] val = new String[1];
                val[0] = result.get(key);
                r.put(key, val);
            }

            String[] val = new String[1];
            val[0] = ((RequestFacade) request).getMethod();
            r.put("_method", val);

            HttpServletRequest s = new MyServletRequestWrapper(((HttpServletRequest) request), r);
            chain.doFilter(s, response);
        } else {
            chain.doFilter(request, response);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
    }
}
```

Request Wrapper:

```
public class MyServletRequestWrapper extends HttpServletRequestWrapper {
    private final HashMap<String, String[]> params;

    public MyServletRequestWrapper(HttpServletRequest request, HashMap<String, String[]> params) {
        super(request);
        this.params = params;
    }

    @Override
    public String getParameter(String name) {
        if (this.params.containsKey(name)) {
            return this.params.get(name)[0];
        }
        return "";
    }

    @Override
    public Map<String, String[]> getParameterMap() {
        return this.params;
    }

    @Override
    public Enumeration<String> getParameterNames() {
        return new Enumerator<>(params.keySet());
    }

    @Override
    public String[] getParameterValues(String name) {
        return params.get(name);
    }
}
```

Authorization Server Configuration (disable Basic Auth for /oauth/token endpoint:

```
    @Configuration
public class AuthorizationServerConfiguration extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

    ...

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer oauthServer) throws Exception {
        oauthServer.allowFormAuthenticationForClients(); // Disable /oauth/token Http Basic Auth
    }

    ...

}
```

Comment: Where do I get the RequestFacade from

Comment: Filter registration is unnecessary in `ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter` - actually it do nothing. What is happening is Spring boot is picking up all `Filter` implementations and register them as standard **servlet** filter not spring security filter, that's why this work.  I struggle with that in non spring boot application.

Answer (score 4):

From the [OAuth 2 specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.13),

> The client makes a request to the token endpoint by sending the
> following parameters using the "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"

Access token request should use `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

In Spring security, the Resource Owner Password Credentials Grant Flow is handled by `ResourceOwnerPasswordTokenGranter#getOAuth2Authentication` in Spring Security:

```
protected OAuth2Authentication getOAuth2Authentication(AuthorizationRequest clientToken) {
    Map parameters = clientToken.getAuthorizationParameters();
    String username = (String)parameters.get("username");
    String password = (String)parameters.get("password");
    UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken userAuth = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(username, password);
```

You can send `username` and `password` to request parameter.

If you really need to use JSON, there is a workaround. As you can see, `username` and `password` is retrieved from request parameter. Therefore, it will work if you pass them from JSON body into the request parameter.

The idea is like follows:

1. Create a custom spring security filter.
2. In your custom filter, create a class to subclass `HttpRequestWrapper`. The class allow you to wrap the original request and get parameters from JSON.
3. In your subclass of `HttpRequestWrapper`, parse your JSON in request body to get `username`, `password` and `grant_type`, and put them with the original request parameter into a new `HashMap`. Then, override method of `getParameterValues`, `getParameter`, `getParameterNames` and `getParameterMap` to return values from that new `HashMap`
4. Pass your wrapped request into the filter chain.
5. Configure your custom filter in your Spring Security Config.

Hope this can help

Answer (score 1):

With Spring Security 5 I only had to add .allowFormAuthenticationForClients() + the JsontoUrlEncodedAuthenticationFilter noted in the other answer to get it to accept json in addition to x-form post data. There was no need to register the resource server or anything.

Answer (score 0):

Also you can modify @jakub-kopřiva solution to support http basic auth for oauth.

Resource Server Configuration:

```
@Configuration
public class ServerEndpointsConfiguration extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    JsonToUrlEncodedAuthenticationFilter jsonFilter;

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .addFilterAfter(jsonFilter, BasicAuthenticationFilter.class)
            .csrf().disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/test").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/secured").authenticated();
    }
}
```

Filter with internal RequestWrapper

```
@Component
public class JsonToUrlEncodedAuthenticationFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {

        if (Objects.equals(request.getServletPath(), "/oauth/token") && Objects.equals(request.getContentType(), "application/json")) {

            byte[] json = ByteStreams.toByteArray(request.getInputStream());

            Map<String, String> jsonMap = new ObjectMapper().readValue(json, Map.class);;
            Map<String, String[]> parameters =
                    jsonMap.entrySet().stream()
                            .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                                    Map.Entry::getKey,
                                    e ->  new String[]{e.getValue()})
                            );
            HttpServletRequest requestWrapper = new RequestWrapper(request, parameters);
            filterChain.doFilter(requestWrapper, response);
        } else {
            filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
        }
    }


    private class RequestWrapper extends HttpServletRequestWrapper {

        private final Map<String, String[]> params;

        RequestWrapper(HttpServletRequest request, Map<String, String[]> params) {
            super(request);
            this.params = params;
        }

        @Override
        public String getParameter(String name) {
            if (this.params.containsKey(name)) {
                return this.params.get(name)[0];
            }
            return "";
        }

        @Override
        public Map<String, String[]> getParameterMap() {
            return this.params;
        }

        @Override
        public Enumeration<String> getParameterNames() {
            return new Enumerator<>(params.keySet());
        }

        @Override
        public String[] getParameterValues(String name) {
            return params.get(name);
        }
    }
}
```

And also you need to allow x-www-form-urlencoded authentication

```
    @Configuration
public class AuthorizationServerConfiguration extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

    ...

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer oauthServer) throws Exception {
        oauthServer.allowFormAuthenticationForClients();
    }

    ...

}
```

With this approach you can still use basic auth for oauth token and request token with json like this:

Header:

```
Authorization: Basic bG9yaXpvbfgzaWNwYQ==
```

Body:

```
{
    "grant_type": "password", 
    "username": "admin", 
    "password": "1234"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can modify @jakub-kopřiva solution to implement only authorization server with below code.

```
 @Configuration
 @Order(Integer.MIN_VALUE)
 public class AuthorizationServerSecurityConfiguration
    extends org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.AuthorizationServerSecurityConfiguration {

      @Autowired
      JsonToUrlEncodedAuthenticationFilter jsonFilter;

      @Override
      protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
             httpSecurity
                   .addFilterBefore(jsonFilter, ChannelProcessingFilter.class);
             super.configure(httpSecurity);
      }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello based on @Jakub Kopřiva answer I have made improvements in order to create working integration tests.
Just so you know, Catalina RequestFacade throws an error in Junit and MockHttpServletRequest, used by mockmvc, does not contain a field "request" as I expect in the filter (therefore throwning NoSuchFieldException when using getDeclaredField()):
`Field f = request.getClass().getDeclaredField("request");`
This is why I used "Rest Assured". However at this point I ran into another issue which is that for whatever reason the content-type from 'application/json' is overwritten into 'application/json; charset=utf8' even though I use `MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE`. However, the condition looks for something like 'application/json;charset=UTF-8' which lies behind `MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE`, and in conclusion this will always be false.
Therefore I behaved as I used to do when I coded in PHP and I have normalized the strings (all characters are lowercase, no spaces).
After this the integration test finally passes.

---- JsonToUrlEncodedAuthenticationFilter.java

```
package com.example.springdemo.configs;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import lombok.SneakyThrows;
import org.apache.catalina.connector.Request;
import org.springframework.core.annotation.Order;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.Enumerator;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

@Component
@Order(value = Integer.MIN_VALUE)

public class JsonToUrlEncodedAuthenticationFilter implements Filter {

    private final ObjectMapper mapper;

    public JsonToUrlEncodedAuthenticationFilter(ObjectMapper mapper) {
        this.mapper = mapper;
    }

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) {
    }

    @Override
    @SneakyThrows
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) {
        Field f = request.getClass().getDeclaredField("request");
        f.setAccessible(true);
        Request realRequest = (Request) f.get(request);

       //Request content type without spaces (inner spaces matter)
       //trim deletes spaces only at the beginning and at the end of the string
        String contentType = realRequest.getContentType().toLowerCase().chars()
                .mapToObj(c -> String.valueOf((char) c))
                .filter(x->!x.equals(" "))
                .collect(Collectors.joining());

        if ((contentType.equals(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE.toLowerCase())||
                contentType.equals(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE.toLowerCase()))
                        && Objects.equals((realRequest).getServletPath(), "/oauth/token")) {

            InputStream is = realRequest.getInputStream();
            try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is), 16384)) {
                String json = br.lines()
                        .collect(Collectors.joining(System.lineSeparator()));
                HashMap<String, String> result = mapper.readValue(json, HashMap.class);
                HashMap<String, String[]> r = new HashMap<>();

                for (String key : result.keySet()) {
                    String[] val = new String[1];
                    val[0] = result.get(key);
                    r.put(key, val);
                }
                String[] val = new String[1];
                val[0] = (realRequest).getMethod();
                r.put("_method", val);

                HttpServletRequest s = new MyServletRequestWrapper(((HttpServletRequest) request), r);
                chain.doFilter(s, response);
            }

        } else {
            chain.doFilter(request, response);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
    }

    class MyServletRequestWrapper extends HttpServletRequestWrapper {
        private final HashMap<String, String[]> params;

        MyServletRequestWrapper(HttpServletRequest request, HashMap<String, String[]> params) {
            super(request);
            this.params = params;
        }

        @Override
        public String getParameter(String name) {
            if (this.params.containsKey(name)) {
                return this.params.get(name)[0];
            }
            return "";
        }

        @Override
        public Map<String, String[]> getParameterMap() {
            return this.params;
        }

        @Override
        public Enumeration<String> getParameterNames() {
            return new Enumerator<>(params.keySet());
        }

        @Override
        public String[] getParameterValues(String name) {
            return params.get(name);
        }
    }
```

[Here is the repo with the integration test](https://github.com/Deviad/springdemo/blob/feature/simple_working_jwt_and_oauth2_example/src/test/java/com/example/springdemo/SpringdemoApplicationTests.java)